# Оптимизация цикла foreach или иное решение (php)

Tags: php, циклы, foreach

Доброго времени суток.

**Условие:** в директории сервера через ftp залито 9000 файлов формата jpg. с названиями (file-1, file-2, file-3 и т д).
**Задача:** вывод одного определенного файла через поле input (текстовое поле) с поиском после 5 символов, начинаем писать само дописывает смысловой файл.

**По типу:** "Сама Картинка" - 100кб. скачать.

Решение не дает покоя и оно следующее:

```
<?php
$dir = opendir(DIR . '/files');
$string_to_search = $_GET['cloth_name'];

$mass_sas[] = "";
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    $mass_sa = strstr($file, $string_to_search);
    if ($mass_sa != "") {
        $mass_sas[] = $mass_sa;
    }
}
closedir($dir); ?>

<? foreach ($mass_sas as $cloth) : ?>

    <? if (!empty($cloth)) : ?>

        <img style="width: 100px; height:100px" src="https://oprime.ru/clothes/files/<?= $cloth ?>">

    <? endif; ?>

<? endforeach; ?>
?>
```

9000 файлов перебирать циклом это нормально ? Есть ли более лучшее решение ? С уважением

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php  - можно найти сразу нужный файл

Comment: <?php
$arFileList = glob("*.jpg");
//Выводим результат
var_dump($arFileList);
?> - получим все 9000 файлов на выходе а нужен один конкретный

Comment: @AikHeidl Так а зачем Вы пытаетесь тогда забирать все jpg? Вы и выводите все нужные по регулярке.

Comment: Дело в том, что каждый файл имеет сове корявое название по типу: fdf-45-vcvv.jpg и менять его название не можно регуляркой ...

Comment: тут вроде как говорят, что ваше решение аналогично варианту в с `glob("*{$stringToSearch}*")`. зы: что по вашему значит перебирать 9к файлов? вы же к файлам по сути вообще не обращаетесь, есть дерево файловой системы, оно хранит имена, структуру и указатели на размещение на диске, упрощенно. Так что фильтр по имени файлов не читает сами файлы, а отправляет запрос к ФС, В целом тот же glob сделаем примерно то же самое, что и вы ручным циклом.

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл хранить связи с файлами где-то в БД. и оттуда выбирать найденные товары, и картинки к ним, или какой там у вас кейс, а не имена файлов дергать